# Rails caches_page on heroku with custom subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, subdomain

Is it possible to make herokus web server perform full page caching uniquely keyed on the subdomain (perhaps using rack middleware?)

ie.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  caches_page :index

  def index
    @content = MyObject.find(request.subdomain)
    ...

subdomain1.myapp.com  >  <cachedir>/subdomain1/index.html
subdomain2.myapp.com  >  <cachedir>/subdomain2/index.html
```

The following techniques require rewrite access to nginx which does not seem to be configurable on heroku:
http://www.agileproductions.com/blog_posts/16-Page-Caching-by-Subdomain-in-Rails-and-Nginx
https://github.com/yeah/page_cache_fu

Answer (score 2):

Page caching on Heroku isn't a great option, as described in the [Caching Strategies for Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies#page-caching) article:

> Rails’s built-in page-caching works by creating a file on the file
>   system. Heroku has an ephemeral file store, so while page caching may
>   appear to work, it won’t work as intended. You should instead use
>   action or fragment caching, or alternatively use Rack::Cache as a
>   reverse proxy to avoid requests to your apps at all.

Instead, it's best to use Rack::Cache with cache store that's shared between dynos. For example, you could use one of the Heroku memcache addons or [AWS ElastiCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/), among other options. Rack::Cache is easy to get running on Heroku; see [Using Rack::Cache with Memcached in Rails 3.1+](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31).

Instead of saying `caches_page` to write the page to the filesystem, you'll specify the desired caching behavior in your HTTP headers, with methods such as [`expires_in`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet.html).  Note that not only do these headers affect your cache, they also affect the browser cache.

"But wait", you ask, "how do I expire a page from Rack::Cache if it could also be held by the users browser?" Answer: you don't. Instead, design your caching to take advantage of [conditional GETs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#conditional-get-support). Revalidation is often easier than manually expiring pages anyway.

Rack::Cache is just a normal HTTP cache that you're layering between the user's browser cache and your web app. See [Things Caches Do](http://tomayko.com/writings/things-caches-do) for a more thorough treatment of what that can mean. The good news is, once you get your caching right, it'll work server-side and client-side. Your app will play nice with caching proxies, and you could even drop in CloudFront or another CDN -- after all, your caching is completely described by standard HTTP headers.

Rack::Cache defaults to including the HTTP Host: header in the cache key, so subdomains are handled automatically. Once you're set up on Heroku, all you need to do is say `expires_in 30.minutes, :public => true`.